# Trying to detect beacons but failed because isMonitoringAvailable always false

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

Hello i trying to detect and ranging beacons following by [apple's docs article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_proximity_to_an_ibeacon)

but in my case `CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self)` always gave me false thus i couldn't start monitoring

Of course i set Privacy for location and Location updates on background mode

this is my codes

```
func initializeLocationManager(){
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}

func rangeBeacons(){
    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
        let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: beacons[0].uuid)!, identifier: beacons[0].identifier)
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }else {
      print("CLLocation Monitoring is unavailable")
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        rangeBeacons()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLBeaconRegion {
        // start monitoring
        if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
            locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)
        }
    }
    print("didEnter at \(region.identifier)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("didExit at \(region.identifier)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beacons.count > 0 {
        let nearestBeacon = beacons.first!
        switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
        case .far:
            print("far")
            break
        case .near:
            print("near")
            break
        case .immediate:
            print("It's behind yout")
            break
        case .unknown:
            print("unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

but if i use `locationManager.startRangingBeacons` directly instead `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)`, it works

but still problem `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` are not called

what is the problem in my case

i want to follow exactly same with apple's docs article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from the code shown what `CLBeaconRegion.self` means in context.  Try instead using the defined region to see if monitoring is available.

```
func rangeBeacons(){
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: beacons[0].uuid)!, identifier: beacons[0].identifier)
    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: region) {
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }else {
       print("CLLocation Monitoring is unavailable")
    }
}
```

In practice, there is no real reason to call `isMonitoringAvailable`.  Just start monitoring without this check.  If for some reason it fails, you will get a callback to: `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError`

Comment: `isMonitoringAvailable` requires a `CLRegion` **class**, not a concrete instance. In Obj-C, this looks like `[CLBeaconRegion class]`, and in Swift, that's the `CLBeaconRegion.self` in the OP's code.

Comment: thanks it works and i forgot to setup bluetooth capabilites

Comment: @DongkunLee, please share your solution as an answer and accept it. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only reason why `isMonitoringAvailable` can be false for iBeacon (`CLBeaconRegion`) is when the device you're running the app on doesn't support Bluetooth 4.0.

This includes:

- the simulator,
- iPhone: 1st-gen, 3G and 3GS,
- iPad: 1st-gen and 2nd-gen,
- iPod Touch: 1st through 4th gen.

If you're running your app on any device newer than these, then the only remaining thing I can think of is, there's a problem with Bluetooth on your device. In which case, a reboot might help.

Comment: i forgot to setup bluetooth on project Thanks!

Comment: Oh, so simply enabling Bluetooth on your device helped?

Comment: Yes! When i use only ranging, it wasn’t necessary. But i think Monotoring needs Bluetooth!